# AutoNumeric - обнуляет полученные значение в input при наведении мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Использую библиотеку `autonumeric.js` , при получении данных через `ajax/json` данные вставляются в `input`, но при наведении мыши на `input` они исчезают. Если отключить `autoNumeric` данные не исчезают (не обнуляются). К сожалению я не смог воспроизвести данную ситуацию в редакторе `stakoverflow`, поэтому просто выложил свой код.

```js
$('#thermForwardStream').focusout(function () {
            var thermForwardStream = $('#thermForwardStream').val();
            var thermBackStream = $('#thermBackStream').val();
            if (thermBackStream == "70" ) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { 'thermForwardStream': thermForwardStream, 'thermBackStream': thermBackStream },
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetDataAnnexY", "ThermLosses")',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#tempHeatExchangerOne').val(data.thermForwardStream);
                $('#tempHeatExchangerTwo').val(data.thermBackStream);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

const autoNumericOptions = {
allowDecimalPadding: "floats",
            decimalCharacter: ",",
            digitGroupSeparator: "",
            emptyInputBehavior: "zero"
};

new AutoNumeric('#thermForwardStream', autoNumericOptions);
new AutoNumeric('#thermBackStream', autoNumericOptions);
new AutoNumeric('#tempHeatExchangerOne', autoNumericOptions);
new AutoNumeric('#tempHeatExchangerTwo', autoNumericOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autonumeric@4.1.0"></script>



<input class="form-control double" type="text" value="0" id="thermForwardStream" name="ThermForwardStream" required />

<input class="form-control double" type="text" value="70" id="thermBackStream" name="ThermBackStream" required />

<input class="form-control double" type="text" id="tempHeatExchangerOne" name="TempHeatExchangerOne" required />

<input class="form-control double" type="text" id="tempHeatExchangerTwo" name="TempHeatExchangerTwo" required />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо добавить  `watchExternalChanges: true` в свойства autoNumeric.

> watchExternalChanges - определяет, должен ли элемент AutoNumeric
>   наблюдать внешние изменения, сделанные без использования .set()
>
> Это позволяет быть в курсе изменений, внесенных непосредственно во
>   входное значение, используя прямой доступ к element.value свойству,
>   например aNElement.node().value = 42.

```
const autoNumericOptions = {
allowDecimalPadding: "floats",
            decimalCharacter: ",",
            digitGroupSeparator: "",
            emptyInputBehavior: "zero",
            watchExternalChanges: true //!!!
};
```